TP4056 load sharing problem, output voltage fluctuates from 2.5 to battery voltage (4~4.2 V)
I'm trying to build a Li-ion battery charger with a TP4056 module (with battery protection) with load sharing so that the connected ESP32 doesn't restart when the external power supply is turned off. The schematic: 

When the ac-dc adapter (which is giving 5V DC at input), is turned off, the voltage at SYS OUT fluctuates from 2.5~2.6 V,  then gradually increases to battery voltage,  usually 3.9~4 V. When the adapter is turned on, then the voltage at SYS OUT is 4.8~4.9 V.

Both LEDs are turned on the TP4056 module when the battery is connected and external 5V is applied at the input,  battery voltage is measured at 4.0~4.1 V in this condition.


The SYS OUT is connected with 3.3V LDO (MCP1925S), when external power is turned off and SYS OUT fluctuates from 2.5 V, the output of LDO isn't 3.3 V, hence the connected ESP32 restarts. I need to build this, so that the ESP32 gets an uninterrupted power supply, 3.3V.
How to solve this?

Check the data sheet for the IRF9540:

It could take as much as 4 V at Vgs for this device to pass just 250 uA.
You don't say how much current you need but it's certain to be much more if you're powering a microcontroller. Find a logic-level MOSFET instead and check the graphs in its datasheet to ensure that it will be able to do the job at the lowest battery voltage you want to operate at.
